# AWS Instance Export Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to export an AWS instance to an S3 bucket for user with our internal virtualization infrastructure. I regularly have to create virtual machines compatible with Hyper-V and VMWare ESX, so the thought process was to upload an OVA to AWS, import it as an AMI for use as our base image, then leverage packer to create the images we need, and export for Hyper-V or VMWare. The issue is, if we export these AMIs in the following way:

`aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-id --disk-image-format VMDK --s3-export-location S3Bucket=my-export-bucket,S3Prefix=exports/`

we get an error when we actually load the VM into Vmware:

"You do not have write access to a partition."

and it gives me the option to override access rights for this write. This does not solve the issue though and I end up receiving an:

"Failure writing sector 0x4600 to hd0" and the system does not work correctly despite working in AWS. So we have also attempted to export via this method:

`aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --instance-id instance-id --target-environment vmware --export-to-s3-task file://C:\file.json`

and we populate the file.json with bucket information etc.in the form:

```
{
    "ContainerFormat": "ova",
    "DiskImageFormat": "VMDK",
    "S3Bucket": "some-bucket-name",
    "S3Prefix": "some-export-path"
}
```

but we receive this error:

An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the CreateInstanceExportTask operation: Bucket must be owned by the same S3 account and READ_ACL and WRITE permissions are required on the destination bucket. Please refer to the API documentation for details.

We have followed all the instructions listed in the official AWS documentation (adding the canonical ID, the bucket is owned by the account making the cli call etc. We followed this guide also as its more 'step-by-step':

https://dev.to/aws-builders/aws-importexport-part-2-export-vm-from-aws-lcm

But we are still receiving permissions issues. Has anyone ever got an image pipeline setup for internal use in this way?